# Bootstrap and responsive menu list and images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This is what I have so far:
http://clients.emagid.com/practice_work/darwin/index.html

What I want the final result is this webpage:
http://php1.emagid.net/~laurenbe/

I'm just doing a practice work on an already finished website. I want to make my responsive Menu button to be in the center (0 auto) when I resize my browser and not fixed to the top right corner as most bootstrap menu buttons do.

Additionally, how do I make it so that when I click the menu button, the menu lists would push down all the content below so that it doesn't stay underneath it? (Try my webpage and see what I mean, instead of pushing down the body content along with the lists, the body content overlaps the lists).

And last but not least, how do I make my images rescale smaller as I resize the browser? (Check my webpage and the finished one).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the button is floating to the right because at line 4300 in bootstrap.min.css there is the rule

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;     <==== problem
    padding: 9px 10px;
   ....
}
```

One solution would be to add the following inside the max-width:767px media query

```
@media (max-width:767px){

   .navbar-toggle {
    float: none;
   }
}
```

The problem of the expanded mobile menu not pushing the main page content is because at line 121 on style.css you have fixed the height of the header:

```
header {
    height: 198px; <== problem
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 710px;   
}
```

You could either remove this height rule, or maybe reset it for in the max-width:767px @mendia block.

To force your images to scale, you could size them based on %. So for example, if you made width:80%; then they would be 80% of their parent element. In practice, this isn't always easy though because you'll need to have multiple @media rules so that the image sizes stays appropriate and doesn't go weird on you when the bootstrap grid collapses at narrow viewport.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're amazing THANKS SO MUCH David for helping me! I fixed the menu button and the content pushing down. Now I'm doing the image scaling. :)

Comment: Thanks @jaegerbomb91, I'm pleased this got you unstuck

Comment: Wish you were my professor! lol, check out the changes I made : http://clients.emagid.com/practice_work/darwin/ , I also applied the bootstrap slideshow to my images. I'm just trying to make the images rescale now

Comment: @jaegerbomb91 the key to this sort of troubleshooting is using the web inspector in Chrome / Safari. It's a mine of information and you'll be well rewarded for time you spend finding out everything you can do with it.